# How to convert certificate from CA to .pfx file?

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I have been struggling since last night to create a .`pfx` file using `OpenSSL`.  I have been following this [document](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/) and have been following the instructions under the `Get a certificate using OpenSSL` header.

I have also tried various things from trawling through posts but my lack of experience in this area is really impeding my efforts.

I am at the step here: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out myserver.pfx -inkey myserver.key -in myserver.crt` and am using the `OpenSSL.exe` console.

I get the error: `unable to load certificates`

I am using IIS 7 and purchased a certificate from Symantec.  I think my problem is that my certificate starts like:

`----BEGIN PKCS #7 SIGNED DATA-----` and not simply `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` so the command in my walk-through is not able to deal with it.

Is this a `.pb7` certificate?

I have a `.key` file and a `.crt` file.  How do I create a .pfx files with the above formats?

Comment: Could you show the whole error? Are you using relative path in the command?

Comment: I will later, I'm not at that PC at the moment but will later.  The files are located in C:\temp\myserver.key or C:\temp\myserver.crt on a laptop running Windows 7 and IIS 7.  The command has those paths referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the certificate from the PKCS#7 container that you appear to have, run

```
openssl pkcs7 -in cert.p7b -print_certs -out cert.cer
```

Than you can use the pkcs12 command you already stated in the question to generate the PKCS#12 (pfx) container.

Comment: thank you.  I will try this evening.  So I eould rename my .crt to .pb7?  How do I then get that .cer to a .pfx?

Comment: You don't have to rename it, you can use whatever name it has right now. I just used that extension for clarification which file format I mean.
As for the pfx-conversion, I appended my answer above